# правильный запрос по дате Oracle sql

Tags: oracle

Не могу понять как сделать запрос по дате. Надо сделать запрос равно или старее даты + 90 дней(грубо говоря 3 месяца), т.е. если я выбрал сегодняшнюю дату(30.04.2011) то надо смотреть поля с созданные более 90 дней назад и старее (30.01.2011) to_date не работает само поле DATA а не VARCHAR в формате 2012-09-05 14:29:57

```
logi.EVENTTIME <= to_date('+RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)+)-90','dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Выходит ошибка Не хватает правой скобки

Comment: Вот это что: `'+RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)+)-90'`?

Comment: @akina да забудьте вы про это, переменная и она прекрасно работает разве что -90 не так

Comment: Блин, что должен подразумевать плюс между двумя скобками??? и какого вообще баланс скобок в литерале не сходится? неужели нельзя НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ текст выкладывать, после того, как это функция вернула значение и оно было подставлено?

Comment: @Akina так оно добавляется, через fastreport возвращает 2012-09-05

Comment: 1) Ну так и показывайте ПОСЛЕ того как оно добавилось. 2) Учитывайте, что поле содержит компонент даты, а значение нет, посему в выборку попадут записи с той же датой, что и переданный литерал только в случае, когда время в поле нулевое. Если нужно с любым временем, то надо литерал увеличить на ещё один день и использовать строгое неравенство.

Comment: @Akina чето почитал и непонял как будет правильнее

Comment: Ну... за `2021-01-01` могут быть записи, скажем, `2021-01-01 00:00:00` и `2021-01-01 12:00:00`. Первая пройдёт твой контроль `column <= date`, вторая нет. Чтобы обе прошли, надо использовать значение `2021-01-01 + 1 день`, т.е. `2021-01-02`, и `column < date`. Обе записи (и даже `2021-01-01 23:59:59`) контроль пройдут, а вот `2021-01-02 00:00:00` уже нет.

Comment: @reddyk Возможно ошибка здесь: `to_date('+RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)+)-90`, посмотрите внимательно, что возвращает это выражение.