# Как указать условие - старше чем заданная в переменной дата?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, форматирование, fastreport

Делаю отчет через FastReport и подключаюсь для вывода данных к БД.

Формат даты  переменной:

```
+RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)+  =  2012-09-05 14:29:57
```

Сам запрос даёт ошибку:

```
logi.EVENTTIME < to_date('(+RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)+)-90')
```

Как будет правильнее всего сделать?

То есть, мне надо чтобы `EVENTTIME` был старше чем `sLastDate` как минимум на 90 дней.

Comment: Вы уже задавали [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1276620). Что нового теперь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим это утверждение в вопросе:

```
+RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)+  =  2012-09-05 14:29:57
```

`RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)` это не переменная, это функция, которая возвращает символьное значение `2012-09-05 14:29:57` как результат выполнения. Этот результат с двух сторон имеет оператор конкатинации  `+` для слияния с текстом запроса.

То есть, просто заменим выражение `+RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)+` его результатом и сравним - ошибочный запрос с правильным:

```
create table logi (eventtime) as
    select add_months (date'2012-09-05', -3)+9 from dual union all   
    select add_months (date'2012-09-05', -3)-1 from dual union all   
    select add_months (date'2012-09-05', -3)-2 from dual 
/
  
select logi.eventtime
from logi 
where logi.EVENTTIME < to_date('(2012-09-05 14:29:57)-90')
/                             --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

select logi.eventtime
from logi 
where logi.EVENTTIME < to_date('2012-09-05 14:29:57', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')-90
/

EVENTTIME
-------------------
2012-06-04 00:00:00
2012-06-03 00:00:00
```